# Colobot 1.3 after installation doesn't see mounted image

Tags: installation, gaming

So i really badly want to play Colobot version 1.3 or 1.8 (not gold edition) **with music**.

There is [original image][1] that installs version 1.3 and contains all music tracks, but after installation game doesn't run with error "Please insert the colobot CD and re-run the game". i mount it with UltraISO into D:\

After installation it creates this key in registry:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Epsitec\Colobot\Setup
```

which has value "CDpath" with "D:" in it.

So, if you might know the reason it won't see the mounted image, please help!

*Edit: i managed to make a NoCD path for 1.3 version. So it now runs without CD, but there is no music, so i want to dig further in order to make music work.*
[1]: https://www.old-games.ru/game/download/get.php?fileid=19981&modal=1

Comment: It may be using some DRM to check whether the CD is original.

Comment: Oh no... Well then it would explain everything

Comment: Why don't you use Colobot gold?

Comment: Because it constantly uses 25% of my cpu thus cpu temperature rises to 100. There is a bug report, but without any solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after 3 days of non-stop searching for answer it turned out that UltraISO just unable to mount this image correctly.

Daemon Tools Lite worked perfectly - game is able to see mounted image. i am so happy and probably i will uninstall UltraISO.